# how to join 4 tables in php laravel?

Tags: php, database, laravel, join

I Want to extract data from 4 tables .

**like sname,cgpa,Group_Cgpa,Room_No and Hostel Name.**

Relation of table is as follows.

**AllotmentApps** has : id,sname,cgpa and grpID (from Group id Table) columns.

**Groups** has : id,Group_CGPA

**Room** has : id, HostelID (From Hostel) and ResidentID (From Group id).

**Hostels** has: id, Name, Total_Rooms.

I'm facing problem in joining the tables. Join with AllotmentApps and Groups works fine, but problem occurs when I joined the Room and Hostel Table.

**Join of AllotmentApps and Groups**

```
public function FinalList()
{   
   $allot_apps = AllotmentApps::join('Groups','Groups.id','AllotmentApps.grpID')->orderBy('Groups.Group_CGPA', 'Desc')->get()->groupBy(
      function($item) { 
        return $item->grpID;
    }
  ) ->take(3);
```

**Join of 4 Tables**

```
public function FinalList()
{   
   $allot_apps = AllotmentApps::select('sname','cgpa','Group_CGPA','Hostel_Name')->join('Groups','Groups.id','AllotmentApps.grpID')->join('Hostels','Hostels.id','Hostels.HostelID')->join('Rooms','Rooms.id','Hostel.HostelID')->orderBy('Groups.id', 'Asc')->get()->groupBy(
      function($item) { 
        return $item->grpID;
    }
  ) ->take(3);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
$allot_apps=AllotmentApps::select('AllotmentApps .sname','AllotmentApps .cgpa','Groups.Group_CGPA','tablename.Hostel_Name')
->join('Groups','Groups.id','=','AllotmentApps.grpID')
->join('Rooms','Rooms.ResidentID','=','Groups.id')
->join('Hostels','Hostels.id','=','Rooms.HostelID')
->orderBy('Groups.id', 'Asc')
->groupBy()
->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public function FinalList()
{  $capasity = Rooms::selectRaw('count(id) as c')->count();
   $allot_apps = Rooms::select('Hostel_Name','Rooms.id','Groups.Group_CGPA','AllotmentApps.sname','AllotmentApps.cgpa')->join('Hostels','Hostels.id','Rooms.HostelID')->join('Groups','Groups.id','Rooms.ResidentID')->join('AllotmentApps','Groups.id','AllotmentApps.grpID')->orderBy('Groups.Group_CGPA', 'Desc')->get()->groupBy(
      function($item) { 
        return $item->grpID;
    }
  ) ->take($capasity);
   // return $allot_apps;
   return view('x', compact('allot_apps'));
      }
```